# why *s and *s++ have the same value in the following situation?

Tags: c, pointers, strchr

```
char *s;
char buf [] = "This is a test";

s = strchr (buf, 't');

if (s != NULL)
    printf ("found a 't' at %s\n", s);
printf("%c\n",*s);
printf("%c\n",*s++);
printf("%c\n",*s++);
printf("%c\n",*s++);
printf("%c\n",*s++);
```

This code outputs:

```
found a 't' at test
t
t
e
s
t
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

In my view, *s should be `t` and *s++ should be `e`. But why they have same value in this code ?

Comment: Is "your view" based on anything?

Comment: Postincrement means execute then increment. Try *(++s)

Comment: s means the beginning address of string s, so *s should be the value which is stored in the address. s++ should be the the next position from the beginning address of string s.

Comment: perhaps you should read a C book?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the expression `*s++`, `++` is the ***post***-increment operator.  That means following happens, in-order:

- The value of `s` is gotten
- Then `s` is incremented
- Then the old value of `s` is de-referenced

So,

```
printf("%c\n",*s);     // Prints the character at s
printf("%c\n",*s++);   // Prints the character at s
                       // ***and then*** increments it
```

They will both print the same character.

---

If you want your example code to behave like you think it should, simply remove the first `printf` without the post-increment on `s`:

```
                        // s points to the 't' 

printf("%c\n",*s++);    // Prints 't'. Afterward, s points to the 'e'
printf("%c\n",*s++);    // Prints 'e'. Afterward, s points to the 's'
printf("%c\n",*s++);    // Prints 's'. Afterward, s points to the 't'
printf("%c\n",*s++);    // Prints 't'. Afterward, s points to the NUL terminator
```

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("%c\n",*s++);
```

is (more or less<sup>1</sup>) equivalent to

```
printf("%c\n",*s);
s++;
```

This is why you see `'t'` printed twice.

The expression `i++` evaluates to the *current* value of `i`, and as a side effect increments the variable.

---

<sup>1.  More or less because `s` will be updated after `*s` is evaluated, but before `printf` is actually called.  Exactly when the side effect of `++` is applied isn't specified, apart that it happen before the next *sequence point*.  In this case, a sequence point occurs after all function arguments have been evaluated and before the function is called.</sup>